# Cancelling a comment upvote

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, voting

I have just accidentally upvoted a comment rather than flagging it. I can't see a way to undo this (like you can do for a question) and once you've upvoted a comment you can't flag it.

I suggest it would be handy to be able to reverse a comment upvote and for upvoted comments to remain flaggable.

Comment: @Sathya You do realize that you can cancel comment upvotes within one minute by clicking again? Where's the `status-declined` in that? Funnily enough, you need to wait 5 seconds to undo the vote...

Comment: @DanielBeck wasn't aware; thanks - updated

Answer (score 4):

As Daniel Beck mentions

> You can cancel comment upvotes within one minute by clicking again

See: **[Should I be able to cancel my up-vote on a comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1170/should-i-be-able-to-cancel-my-up-vote-on-a-comment)**

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Shame it was originally declined as the problem seems to be a UI design issue and inconsistent with the ability to up/downvote questions.